# Different types of form helpers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, helper

I'm newish to rails, and scaffolding generates form elements like this:

```
<%= f.label :completed_at %>
```

and the form helper documentation for rails talks about them in a different form, as functions:

```
<%= label( :giveaway, :completed_at, "Closing Date", :class => "control-label" ) %>
```

Where can I find the documentation for the former? is there a name for this version of a form helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `<%= f.label :completed_at %>` refers to item `f` during the iteration through a `form builder` object
2. `<%= label( :giveaway, :completed_at, "Closing Date", :class => "control-label" ) %>` is a static method aka "form helper" method used to generate any label on the fly, not necessarily in the context of a form builder object

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html may help

I would just call it a form label helper.

Comment: this *sortof* helps; after reading through, i found that iterating through form items using `form_for` generates a `form builder` object. and the documentation actually exists there, and not in the area of form helpers